# What is the url where an express app is located at inside an electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron

I am not sure I am doing this quite right. My end goal is to send a post request from a lambda function to my electron app and create a system notification. Locally I have been able to do it from post man, but when I install the app (on linux) It doesn't work, now I am not sure where I am supposed to point my request to, in development I pointed it too. http://localhost:3000/notify what happens when you install the app. How would I send a post request to the app, eventually I want to build user accounts, so I will need to send requests to each separate user based on the lambda logic.

I am using express with electron, is there another way to handle post requests.

Here is my code so far in my main.js file

```
"use strict";
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const { Notification } = require("electron");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// Create a new instance of express
const appE = express();

// Tell express to use the body-parser middleware and to not parse extended bodies
appE.use(bodyParser.json());

// Route that receives a POST request to /sms
appE.post("/notify", function (req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log(body);
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");

  function showNotification() {
    const notification = {
      title: "Basic Notification",
      body: `You sent: ${body.message} to Express`,
    };
    new Notification(notification).show();
  }

  app.whenReady().then(createWindow).then(showNotification);
  res.send(`You sent: ${body.message} to Express`);
});

// Tell our app to listen on port 3000
appE.listen(3000, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: So your webserver locally, but once you deploy it to a server it no longer works? How are you posting to your server? Can you provide a step by step process of what you're doing on local environment and server environment?

Comment: Im not sure I understand, I am not deploying the app, it's an electron app so it is installed on the os. And I am just sending a post request with postman with a message to to localhost:3000. What I am wondering is how would one achieve communciating between a aws lambda function and a app built in electron, since it is installed on the computer and doesn't have a url I can send post requests too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. An HTTP server run inside your Electron app won't generally be accessible to anything running outside of the user's local network, so your Lambda function won't be able to connect to it.

If you want to read notifications from a Lambda function, then you'll need to poll it (make Ajax requests on a timer).

If you want to push messages from the server to the application, then you still need to initiate the connection from the client (so that the connection can be made outside of the user's local network). The typical approach for this is to use Websockets. These are not Lambda function friendly though since they need to be Always On, so you would need to host a server listening for Websocket connections on some other system (like EC2). If your infrastructure is already geared up for Lambda functions then you could write one which, when triggered, sends a message to your EC2 server to trigger Websocket messages.

```
+-------+              +-------+                +-------+
|       |   HTTP       |       |                |       |
|   λ   |   Request    |HTTP   |   Websocket    |Client |
|       ----------------Server ------------------       |
+-------+              +-------+                +-------+
```

Comment: Just to be clear, but I think you have answered my question here, I could write a lambda that sends a request to a EC2 (not ES2 as written) server that is actively listening for websocket connections from a electron app. If so I will spend the time going down that rabbit hold and choose your answer. Thanks for the help thus far. Is on method preferred over the other, polling the lambda function with ajax or using websockets ec2 and lambda?

Comment: Yes. Both have their advantages. Polling is much simpler and means you don't need to add a continuous server the mix. Having a server will have faster reaction time and could be cheaper in terms of resources, especially at scale.

Comment: That said, I have just found https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/ so you might not have to go down the EC2 route.

Comment: oh very interesting, I just started on the EC2 side, but I will take a look at this as well. thanks for all the help

Comment: so this makes sense to me how it's setup, and this may eventually have to be a separate question, but is it possible to have a incoming request from a entirely separate spot (actually a heardware device running node on wifi) That would connect to the api-gateway, and be able to relay a message to the electron app via websockets. I think it's possible, but I dont want to go down this rabbit hold with it being not possible.

Comment: I don't see why not.  [This diagram](https://d2908q01vomqb2.cloudfront.net/1b6453892473a467d07372d45eb05abc2031647a/2018/12/18/websockets-arch.png) shows a Lambda function sending a message back to a websocket client. You can trigger lambda functions from HTTP requests. So your hardware device can use its wifi connection to make an HTTP request to the lambda function which responds by sending data to the connected websocket clients.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is executing the express app as a child process which is using port 3000.

So whenever a user runs this application, the express server will be hosted on their local machines and will be listening to the port requests from port 3000.

But unfortunately, you can't make the post request to this application.

Why? They are not using server OS and this app will be able to listen to only requests from the local network and etc. All in all, I think your way is a little bit wrong. As well, I wonder if there will be anybody who will open their port to receive the requests from anywhere. As this is too risky for users...